# creating a opendj replication topology

Tags: opendj

I am creating a replication topology with opendj. I need two master servers and some slaves. But slaves should be connected to only one of the masters at a time.
But every time I create a slave, it is automatically connected to all other servers like in a fully meshed network. 
How can I get a particular connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enabling replication with OpenDJ, by default the server starts a "Replication Service" which will connect to all other replication services known in the topology.
But it's possible to enable replication without starting the replication service, just connecting to a remote one, using the options --noReplicationServer(1/2)

Assume server1 is one of the masters with replication enabled. You can use dsreplication enable -host1 server1 ... -host2 newSlave --noReplicationServer2 ...

This is somehow documented in the Replication Section of the Admin Guide (but not entirely, and I'm opening an issue for doc to improve) :  http://docs.forgerock.org/en/opendj/2.6.0/admin-guide/index/chap-replication.html#repl-dedicated-servers

I hope this helps.

Comment: oh..thanks..I had read it but didn't realised its importance at that point.